# SourceLocationProvider.CollectMapping does not update when workflow modified

Tags: c#, .net, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation

I'm working on implementing VisualTracking for a rehosted workflow designer. If the file is freshly loaded into the WorkflowDesigner, the visual tracking works fine and mappings generated from `SourceLocationProvider.CollectMapping` work successfully. However, if a modification is made to the workflow and it is resaved the SourceLocationProvider only maps from the original xaml.

Is there any way to force the AttachedProperties that SourceLocationProvider uses under the hood to update?

If one tries to use `WorkflowDesigner.Load(..)` one has create an entirely new WorkflowDesigner object as a WorkflowDesigner can only Load a file once. I would like to avoid this if possible because it loses any debugging data that has been setup.

Answer (score 1):

Using reflection, one could fetch the required information right from the `DebuggerService` itself. The following solution worked for me, and kept working after updating the workflow:

```
private static Dictionary<string, SourceLocation> CreateSourceLocationMapping(
    IDesignerDebugView debugView,
    ModelService modelService)
{
    var nonPublicInstance = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic;
    var debuggerServiceType = typeof(DebuggerService);
    var ensureMappingMethodName = "EnsureSourceLocationUpdated";
    var mappingFieldName = "instanceToSourceLocationMapping";
    var ensureMappingMethod = debuggerServiceType.GetMethod(ensureMappingMethodName, nonPublicInstance);
    var mappingField = debuggerServiceType.GetField(mappingFieldName, nonPublicInstance);

    if (ensureMappingMethod == null)
        throw new MissingMethodException(debuggerServiceType.FullName, ensureMappingMethodName);
    if (mappingField == null)
        throw new MissingFieldException(debuggerServiceType.FullName, mappingFieldName);

    var rootActivity = modelService.Root.GetCurrentValue() as Activity;
    if (rootActivity != null) 
        WorkflowInspectionServices.CacheMetadata(rootActivity);

    ensureMappingMethod.Invoke(debugView, new object[0]);
    var mapping = (Dictionary<object, SourceLocation>) mappingField.GetValue(debugView);

    return (from pair in mapping
            let activity = pair.Key as Activity
            where activity != null
            select new {activity.Id, pair.Value})
        .ToDictionary(p => p.Id, p => p.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, haven't tried this myself, but could you call SourceLocationProvider.CollectMapping(...) from the ModelChanged event of the designer?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's too late but might be it will help to others. So her is my solution

```
private Dictionary<object, SourceLocation> UpdateSourceLocationMappingInDebuggerService()
    {    
       Dictionary<object, SourceLocation> sourceLocationMapping = new Dictionary<object, SourceLocation>();
       Dictionary<object, SourceLocation> designerSourceLocationMapping = new Dictionary<object, SourceLocation>();

       MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(this.WorkflowDesigner.Text));
       DynamicActivity activityToRun = ActivityXamlServices.Load(ms) as DynamicActivity;

       WorkflowInspectionServices.CacheMetadata(activityToRun);
       Activity documentRootElement = GetRootWorkflowElement(rootInstance);
       Activity rootActivity = GetRootRuntimeWorkflowElement(this.workflowToRun);
       var fileName = this.WorkflowDesigner.Context.Items.GetValue<WorkflowFileItem>().LoadedFile;

       SourceLocationProvider.CollectMapping(rootActivity, documentRootElement, sourceLocationMapping, fileName);
       SourceLocationProvider.CollectMapping(documentRootElement, documentRootElement, designerSourceLocationMapping, fileName);

           if (this.debuggerService != null)
            {
                ((DebuggerService)this.debuggerService).UpdateSourceLocations(designerSourceLocationMapping);
            }

           if (designerSourceLocationMapping.Count != sourceLocationMapping.Count)
            {
                foreach (var item in designerSourceLocationMapping)
                {
                    if (!sourceLocationMapping.ContainsValue(item.Value))
                        sourceLocationMapping.Add(item.Key, item.Value);
                }
            }

       this.designerSourceLocationMapping = designerSourceLocationMapping;
       return sourceLocationMapping;
   }
```

here I am updating sourceLocationMapping again after

> ((DebuggerService)this.debuggerService).UpdateSourceLocations()